# Avoid auto lowercase first letter in asp.net json response

Tags: asp.net, json, razor

In my asp.net razor project, json response always lowercase the first letter, which is annoying. Since I would then deal with different names from backend to frontend.

My Class:

```
    [JsonProperty("Test")]
    public string Test { get; set; } => json responce: Test (good)

    public string Test2 { get; set; } => json responce: test2 (bad)

    [JsonPropertyName("Test3")]
    public string Test3 { get; set; }  => json responce: test3 (bad)
```

Can I avoid adding a JsonProperty markup on every value field?

Comment: Why do you care about having lowercase on the front end? That's actually the normal thing to do which is why .NET does it by default.

Comment: For a consistent naming. Especially my data has fields like CT_Image which would be come cT_image, which does not look right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your custom **formatter** or use **DefaultContractResolver** by giving **NamingStrategy**. For e.g. check below code:

```
User user = new User
{
    UserName = "jamesn",
    Enabled = true
};

DefaultContractResolver contractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
{
    NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user1, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = contractResolver,
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
});

Console.WriteLine(json);
```